# Kentico CMS 5 - give user role access to content properties tab

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

I want to give a user role access to the content properties tab for my pages in Kentico CMS. I have managed to make the tab visible via Module properties however i still get the message stating that they do not have correct permission.

I cannot seem to see anywhere that will let me provide access to this area.

Answer (score 2):

1. Have you setup the correct UI Personalization options for that role ?

http://devnet.kentico.com/Blogs/Petr-Vozak/January-2010/Kentico-CMS-5-0---UI-personalization.aspx

[image]

2. Is UI Personalization enabled ?  Site Manager -> Settings -> Security & Membership -> Enable UI personalization
3. Have you made sure that user role has rights to CMSDesk itself ?

Comment: I've also been caught out by not checking the 'Is Editor' box under the account general settings.